# Web Page Embed to Another Web Page issue

Tags: wordpress, embed

I'm facing a unique situation I'm hoping to see if anyone has advice or knows how to resolve.

I have 2 websites.  Bchipmedia.com which is a WordPress site.  The other is BlueCHipMedia.info which is HTML.  All of my main SEO, pages, etc are on BCHipMedia.com. I really wanted the .info to display as the homepage for the .com site since the .info is a single page site.  I embedded the .info into a page on the .com site with this code:

```
<embed style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;" src="http://bluechipmedia.info" width="100%" height="100%"></embed>
```

So my homepage on BChipMedia.com now has the BlueCHipMedia.info embedded. 
The .info site is a single page and the issue I'm experiencing is that on the .info site I link back to a couple of the .com pages.  Since the user is viewing this as an embed, when a user clicks a link via the homepage, the actual page doesn't change, but the embedded site does.  This results in the inability to scroll on the new page.  I'm noticing this issue on smaller screens.  Any thoughts or advice on different approaches?

Comment: I found a workaround.  I removed existing buttons/links from the embedded website.  I then added a menu to the page of the embed.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the workaround, I still have the scrolling issue on desktop with two scroll bars; The outer one isn't allowed me to scroll properly either.

I recently wrote a plugin that might help you though, it's called [Content Mask](https://xhynk.com/content-mask/) - you can see it in the repository [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-mask/).

If you install and activate it, you can make a regular page (go ahead and call it "Home Page") and then set it as your Home Page in **Settings** > **Reading**.

With Content Mask installed and activated, on the new **Home Page** page will be a meta box for Content Mask.

- Enable it by clicking on the check mark.
- Paste the URL: (in your case `bluechipmedia.info`).
- Try using the Download method first.
- If the Download method doesn't work, you can try the Iframe method instead.

[image: Here's a preview of the metabox as of plugin version 1.4.3.1]

What the plugin does is fetches the content from the URL you typed in: `bluechipmedia.info` and kills the original page request displays that instead of the page or post content you have, either by replacing the content with the stored [WP Transient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API), a full screen borderless iframe, or 301 redirection.